# xpath query to get other siblings by searching with array of values

Tags: arrays, xml, search

```
<multiRef id="id178" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns9:Map" xmlns:ns9="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<key xsi:type="soapenc:string">templateContainerNames</key>
<value soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[4]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
<value xsi:type="xsd:string">APM</value>
<value xsi:type="xsd:string">OPERATING_SYSTEM</value>
<value xsi:type="xsd:string">Unix_Virtual</value>
<value xsi:type="xsd:string">UNIX_HOST</value>
</value>
</item>   
<key xsi:type="soapenc:string">Name</key>
<value xsi:type="soapenc:string">Unix_Remote_without_SSHKey</value>
</item>
</multiRef>
```

I have the sample xml file and I would like to get value of 'Name' by passing `templateContainerNames` array values: `[APM,OPERATING_SYSTEM,Unix_Virtual,UNIX_HOST]`.

How can I do this?

Comment: _" I would like to get value of 'Name' by passing templateContainerNames array values"_ By passing them where? How are you evaluating the XPath? It has no concept of arrays.

Comment: I am very new to xml query, i didn't know it has no array. 
In the given xml sample, I know only the values APM, OPERATING_SYSTEM, Unix_Virtual and UNIX_HOST and I want to search by these values and get 'Unix_Remote_Without_SSHKey'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution myself. I found some clue on arrays somewhere and tried below query and it worked perfectly.

//value[value[1]='APM' and value[2]='OPERATING_SYSTEM' and value[3]='Unix_Virtual' and value[4]='UNIX_HOST']/../parent::*/item[key="Name"]/value

Thanks
Srinivas